# page reload with success message php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

i am trying above but message is displayed on php page.instead of reloading on index page AND DISPLAY MESSAGE ABOVE SUBSCRIBE FORM ITS REDIRECTING TO PHP PAGE.You can check on test site link attached.Form is on index 
page.I tried to reload page through jquery onload and onclick onsubmit but didn't worked.below are test which i did.

```
//form is on index.html page
       <!-- your form here -->

   <form action="forms/subscribe.php"id="form" method="post">


    <input type="email"  name="email" placeholder="Enter your Email">
    <input type="submit" value="Subscribe">
               </form>

   //form is on index.html page
```

My php page

```
<?php


// My Code goes here form to email
```

header.location(Location: /index.html)

```
   ?>
```

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre], and then edit your question accordingly. And please don’t refer to outside stuff (_“best explanation at …”_), but give us a _proper_ explanation directly inside your question.

Comment: @CBroe updated code is it ok

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use js variable values after reload. You need to do things without reloading the page means you just need to update the content and control your HTML tags.

The above example you mentioned. They are not reloading the page, they are getting values from input box then hide that div. After hiding the div they are showing another div with the information.

For your solutions you can do the same but remember to reset input values for every request.

Comment: ok but how to do that i want page reload on same page not on action="/action_page.php" as i form data will be sent to email

Comment: you dont need to reload the page using jquery if you sending post request. Or you can try ajax request.

Comment: what actual message you want to print after post request?

Comment: header('Location: /index.html'); reloads but their is no success message on index.php.can kindly check on site url....used onsubmit alert() but irrespective of form validation it pops up.used if else  but ..didnt work.....

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in PHP with page reloads if you store a message in the session. At the top of each page make sure that the first line is

```php
session_start()
```

Then on the page that receives the data set a session message

```php
$_SESSION['message'] = 'Some Value';
```

Then on your page with the form you check to see if the session has a message. If it does, display it and then clear it.

```php
if(isset($_SESSION['message']) {
    echo $_SESSION['message'];
    session_unset('message');
}
```

Comment: can you replicate code and check ,,pulling off my head as of now : )

Answer (score 0):

some silly syntax error
using onsubmit="alert()"

```
<script>
   function alert() {
   alert("Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.!");
     }
     </script>
```

on subscribe page`header('Location: /index?message=success');`